# Xcode debugging (breakpoint) issue

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode6, conditional-breakpoint

I'm writing an `iOS` app in `Objective-C` for iOS 8.4 with Xcode 6.4. I have a variable (actually an item in an array) changing in unexpected ways.

In order to find out what is going on, I would like to have a way to make the program pause when a change on the variable is about to happen (or just happened), using some kind of `“special break point”`.

Is this possible, if YES how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a Watchpoint (see "Setting Watchpoints" [here](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html)).

Basically they monitor memory for *writes* and break the program when that happens.

I think you can only set them from the debugging console, not the Xcode UI, with:

```
(lldb) watchpoint set variable myinstancevar
```

or

```
(lldb) w s v myinstancevar
```

Comment: The problem here is that he wants to make debugger stop on any change on the Array. The array will always have the same pointer in memory even tho you add or remove obejcts. Watchpoints only track changes on memory places. So if you change the array from nil to something then it will stop. But changes on the array won't.

Comment: @Pauls, thats wrong, any change on variable itself will stop. For instance, add simple integer inside some class, and add increment on several different places. set watchpoint and you will see that everytime you called increment program will stop ( with old and new value)

Comment: I just tested and doesn't work. I created a mutablearray in a class. I added a watchpoint into that variable. Then, as I scrolled I was adding objects into that array to check if it stops. It doesn't. Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: @Pauls My assumption was that the OP would put the watchpoint on the object being added to the array.

Comment: I am looking in that now,  but it doesn't seem to be possible to watch an element of an array, unless it requires a particular syntax I haven't found.
And when I watch the array itself, I do not catch any change.

Comment: @Michel You'll need to find out the object address before it's added to the array.  Add the watchpoint on that address and then continue.  There is no array syntax AFAIK.

Comment: It doesn't work because watchpoint watchs memory addresses changes. NSarray contains the property (readonly) count. It seems that internally they don't have an actual ivar, they just compute the size everytime you call count. So we can't place a watchpoint on it.

Comment: as @trajanfoe says, placing a breakpoint on the object being modified instead of the array would work.

Comment: I was finally able to make it work, using the address of the element in the array.